# I wanna know how this would be done with pine script

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, indicator, pine-script-v4

Hey guys I'm very new to pine script and even to stackoverflow and I want to create an indicator which goes as following:

HC= Last candle High - Current Price
LC= Last candle Low -  Current Price
The Results we get from above will be in pips and we'll calculate position size with them like that:
HC= 10 pips
LC= 20 pips
Risk 2%
Equity= $1000

1000/100×2/HC
1000/100×2/LC

So that's all I want into an indicator I think there must be inputs for equity and risk so if anyone wants to show some generosity please help me with that I know this would be very easy for a skilled programmer.

Thanks

Comment: hi, please share the code also that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the HC using formula  (high[1] - close)/syminfo.mintick and LC using formula (low[1] - close)/syminfo.mintick. And then calculate  the position based on them and plot in different color. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator("buysell")
HC= (high[1] - close)/syminfo.mintick
LC= (low[1] - close)/syminfo.mintick
HPos=1000/100*2/HC
LPos=1000/100*2/LC
plot(HPos,color=color.green)
plot(LPos,color=color.red)
```